# SQL Server substring(substring())

Tags: sql-server

Using two times the substing() is giving me an error.
Is there a way to get the same result ?

```
select [Identifiant] as [ID payment],
       [Etat de la dépense] as [Status payment],
       [Code bénéficiaire] as [Recipient code of payment],
       substring(substring([Information projet], 83, 100) as [sting], 1, PATINDEX('%Code Branche%', [string])-1) as [Recipient of payment]
 into [DB].[dbo].[Check_Result]
 from [DB].[dbo].Expenses_SAP$
```

Comment: What is the error? And sample data will help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site and be sure to read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Follow the guidelines here should give you some answers... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this what you're hoping for? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0037e1c1ad0bb6ba063193d24977a03

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by using CHARINDEX() with SUBSTRING(). Have a look at this built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't alias the inner substring.  It's unclear what you would try to achieve by  doing this, so I can't really suggest the correct way to do whatever it is.

Take out `as [sting]` and at least you should have valid syntax:

```
substring(substring([Information projet], 83, 100), 1, PATINDEX('%Code Branche%', [string])-1) as [Recipient of payment]
```

Comment: There is another alias which you missed to remove after PATINDEX. substring(substring([Information projet], 83, 100),1, PATINDEX('%Code Branche%',[Information projet])-1) as [Recipient of payment]

Comment: @Ayush I didn't miss it.   That alias ( `as [Recipient of payment]` ) is correct syntax, as it aliases the entire column, and not just an inner portion of it.   So I assume it's intended and is valid.   It's not directly after the PATINDEX, it's after the closing of the outer SUBSTRING.

Comment: check the parameters of PATINDEX. it doesn't appear right to me.

Comment: It is correct if the table has a column named `[String]`.   Without clarification from the original poster, I'm not ready to assume it doesn't.

Comment: Then i get that, seeing the substring and the way the original poster was trying to get it is use first substring and alias it is as String and then do the PATINDEX on the sub setted string. So, I understand the question is not so clear.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I think Ayush is correct... If you look back at the OPs original script, he's trying to alias the inner substring as [string]... "substring([Information projet], 83, 100) as [sting]" and then tried referencing that alias in the patindex function.

Comment: @JasonA.Long I can see how that could be correct, but until OP confirms one way or the other I'll keep my answer as is, since it at least fixes the obvious syntax error.   You're assuming `[sting]` is a typo, and it probably is, but it might not be.   There isn't enough clarity in the question to be sure of the author's intent.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I don't think it's a typo. I think the OP is trying to avoid typing "(substring([Information projet], 83, 100)" multiple times... Using a made up syntax that doesn't work.

Comment: @JasonA.Long I know, and I understand why you think that.  But I won't put any further effort into my answer until the OP makes the effort to clarify the question.   : )

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you're trying to do something like the following...

```
SELECT 
    es.Identifiant as [ID payment],
    es.[Etat de la dépense] as [Status payment],
    es.[Code bénéficiaire] as [Recipient code of payment],
    substring(ss.sub_string, 1, PATINDEX('%Code Branche%', ss.sub_string)-1) as [Recipient of payment]
    into [DB].[dbo].[Check_Result] 
 FROM 
    DB.dbo.Expenses_SAP es
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (substring([Information projet], 83, 100)) ) ss (sub_string);
```